# How to change the language of the custom post?

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

I am using `polylang` plugin for multiple language in my project. I created a custom Event using following code.

```
function post_types()
{
    $labels = array(
        "name"          => "Events",
        "add_new_items" => "Add New Event",
        "edit_item"     => "Edit Event",
        "all_items"     => "All Events",
        "singular_name" => "Event"
    );

    $events = array(
        "has_archive" => true,
        "public"      => true,
        "menu_icon"   => "dashicons-calendar",
        "labels"      => $labels,
    );
    register_post_type("event", $events);
}

add_action("init", "post_types");
```

I am not sure how can I change the language of the posts inside this event?

Comment: You must need to use `text domain` for each your labels which are visible - https://polylang.pro/doc/multilingual-custom-post-types-and-taxonomies/ here you may understand how you can translate your custom post types and taxonomies

Answer (score 1):

Please use a text domain:

```
function post_types()
{
    $labels = array(
        "name"          => __( "Events", "your-text-domain" ),
        "add_new_items" => __( "Add New Event", "your-text-domain" ),
        "edit_item"     => __( "Edit Event", "your-text-domain" ),
        "all_items"     => __( "All Events", "your-text-domain" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Event, "your-text-domain" )"
    );

    $events = array(
        "has_archive" => true,
        "public"      => true,
        "menu_icon"   => "dashicons-calendar",
        "labels"      => $labels,
    );
    register_post_type("event", $events);
}

add_action("init", "post_types");
```

Then create a language file(.po/.mo) for your desired language. I basically use Loco Translate Plugin for creating a language file.

Learn More:https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/internationalization/localization/

Comment: What is your-text-domain mean?

Comment: It can be anything that needs to initialized before using "load_plugin_textdomain" for plugin and "load_theme_textdomain" for theme. Please see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_theme_textdomain/#user-contributed-notes and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_plugin_textdomain/#user-contributed-notes